# How to create a horizontal margin between divs with Bootstrap 4 scss

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to learn to use Bootstrap and Sass. I'm stuck at something seemingly simple, but I just can't get it to work. How to create a margin between the divs below?

I tried to insert margin-top or margin-bottom at every div but I can't get the result I'm looking for. I tried to wrap the divs in containers and inserted rows in different ways, but after all this time I don't know what to look for anymore. Every time a div just becomes longer or shorter after adding a margin. The divs keep sticking to each other because of their background colors. I would like to have white space in between of them.

How to adjust the scss to get this done?

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main_body"><div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="main_content">
            <div class="main_items">
                <div class="profileTabs"></div>
                <div class="profileHead"></div>
                <div class="interests"></div>
                <div class="profileLabels"></div>
            </div>
----------------------------------margin-------------------------------
            <div class="item">
                <div class="avatars"></div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="avatars"></div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.container {
  @include make-container();
  .main_body {
    @include make-row();
    .sidebar {
      @include make-col-ready();
      @include make-col(1.8, 12);
      margin-right: 15px;
    }
    .profileTabs {
      @include make-col-ready();
      @include make-col(10, 10);
    }
    .main_content {
      @include make-col-ready();
      @include make-col(10, 12);
      .main_items {
        @include make-row();
        .profileHead {
          @include make-col-ready();
          @include make-col(2, 10);
        }
        .interests {
          @include make-col-ready();
          @include make-col(2, 10);
        }
        .profileLabels {
          @include make-col-ready();
          @include make-col(2, 10);
        }
      }
      .item {
        @include make-row();
        .avatars {
          @include make-col-ready();
          @include make-col(2.2, 10);
        }
        .content {
          @include make-col-ready();
          @include make-col(7.8, 10);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your using Bootstrap 4, what about trying the [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation) provided?

Comment: Doesn't appear that you're using any of the Bootstrap classes.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to do that actually. There's only a make-col and make-col-ready mixin. I was already very happy to be able to get all the boxes in place with the Bootstrap grid. That wouldn't be possible without sass. I started off with this cool blog post: http://willschenk.com/bootstrap-advanced-grid-tricks/ Now I'm just trying to get further. I can't find many examples or tutorials on how to define bootstrap yourself. It would be great if you know more articles like Will Schenk's or http://www.helloerik.com. for example.

Comment: Adding spacing classes to a div is the same as adding a margin to a div right? I tried adding a few classes to the divs, but the divs just become longer, they get stretched. They will not seperate. It feels like I must be missing a column or a row.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `<hr>`.

This may be what you're looking for.

Here's an example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2cghk57/)

Comment: That didn't work. If I put <hr> in between of both divs, the div on top seems to become longer. The <hr> seems to appear at the bottom of "main_items" In the the console it's clear the <hr> is below  "main_items", but it inherits the same background color as "main_items". So it still won't seperate both divs...

Comment: You can apply css attributes to the `<hr>` using a class `<hr class="spacer">` you can then apply margins, padding and colour.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I wish it would work, but when adding margin to <hr>,  "main_items" still seems to become longer. I think the structure in the scss file must be wrong, but I can't see it clearly anymore now.